# Cell numbers not displaying in html export of ipynb in vs code

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to create an html export of a Jupyter Notebook from VS Code. However, the cell numbers don't show up when I do this.

I've looked through various settings, but can't find anything specific to this.

Here's what it looks like in the notebook: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Kn9I.png)

and in the html file: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5cPI.png).

Comment: Is the output showing up? Or does it look un-run otherwise? Are you using a command to do it it? You may want to try `jupyter nbconvert` and use a template, see [here](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#html). Example command at [this issue post](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/issues/1316).

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/discussions/14939